# when each element not visible, change its position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using $.each to find each "screen" on my webpage. I want something to happen when each screen becomes visible and then for that action to reverse itself when the element is no longer visible. It's that last part that isn't working.

I'm using the jquery visible plugin.

jquery:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() { //check for visibles    
$.each($(".picture"), function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($(this).visible(true)) {

                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $this.children('.cutline_background').animate({"left":"0px"},2500, function(){});
                        $this.children('.text').animate({"left":"40px"},2500, function(){});
                    }, 3000);

                } else{
                    $this.children('.cutline_background').css("left", "-20%");  
                    $this.children('.text').css("left", "-20%");                                                                              }
            });
});
```

The visible part works. What am I doing wrong, though, on the not visible part? It doesn't seem to recognize my "this" any more.

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `var $this = $(this);`? Also as per my uderstanding `$(this).visible(true)` should be `$this.is(':visible')`

Comment: @Satpal: I'm scrolling down the page. When something comes into view, it's visible. Has nothing to do with css.

Comment: And @Satpal comment has nothing to do with CSS too. It's about useless redeclaring of `$this` inside of `if` and about error with checking element's visibility in this `if`.

Comment: Even if I take it out, the not visible part doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you to provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code, so that we will be able to see it and to fix it.

Comment: By the way, element's visibility checking stays incorrect and in updated answer.

Comment: @Regent, I'm using the visible plugin for jquery. https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible

Comment: Okay, now I see that it is really should be so, but what about fiddle with your code/example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/os1trfsm/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in messing elements' hiding with delayed showing. For example, you scroll to element, timeout for showing is set, then you scroll away from this, hiding is applied, and then animation for showing is fired up.

I suggest to keep state of objects (for example, using `data-state`) and check it before doing showing and hiding to handle all these situations.

Example of how it can be done is in [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/os1trfsm/1/).

The only minor problem that I didn't fix is resetting timeout when you scroll away from element and scroll to it back during timeout.

Full code:

```
var isHidden = 0;
var isAnimated = 1;
var isShown = 2;
var shouldBeHidden = 3;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".picture").data('state', isHidden);

    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        $(".picture").each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var thisIsVisible = $this.visible(true);
            var thisState = $this.data('state');
            if (thisIsVisible && thisState == isHidden)
            {
                $this.data('state', isAnimated);            
                setTimeout
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        showElement($this);
                    },
                    3000
                );
            }
            else if (thisIsVisible && thisState == shouldBeHidden)
            {
                $this.data('state', isAnimated); 
            }
            else if (!thisIsVisible && thisState == isShown)
            {
                hideElement($this);
            }
            else if (!thisIsVisible && thisState == isAnimated)
            {
                $this.data('state', shouldBeHidden); 
            }
        }); 
    });
});

function showElement($this)
{
    if ($this.data('state') == shouldBeHidden)
    {
        $this.data('state', isHidden);
        return;
    }
    $this.children('.cutline_background').animate
    (
        {
            "left": "0px"
        },
        2500
    );
    $this.children('.text').animate
    (
        {
            "left": "40px"
        },
        2500,
        function()
        {
            if ($this.data('state') == shouldBeHidden)
            {
                hideElement($this);
            }
            else
            {
                $this.data('state', isShown);
            }
        }
    );
}

function hideElement($this)
{
    $this.children('.cutline_background').css("left", "-20%");  
    $this.children('.text').css("left", "-20%");
    $this.data('state', isHidden);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Regent, but this code works the same as my present code - the element slides out fine, but it never resets.

Comment: @LauraNMS you mean `.cutline_background` is still shown on element even after you scroll away from this element and becomes not visible? If so - are sure that you really scroll away from element and it is really not visilble?

Comment: Yes, but see my answer above.

Comment: @LauraNMS I've seen your answer, but it has the same problem with delayed showing. And I still don't know what is wrong in my fiddle, because it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the waypoint plugin instead of the visible plugin, and that is working:

```
$(".picture").waypoint(function(direction){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (direction === "down") {
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $this.children('.cutline_background').animate({"left":"0px"},2500, function(){});
                    $this.children('.text').animate({"left":"40px"},2500, function(){});
                }, 3000);

        }
        if (direction === "up") { 
            $this.children('.cutline_background').css("left", "-20%");  
            $this.children('.text').css("left", "-20%");

        }
    });
```

Comment: After more experimentation, I gave up on this idea altogether. It was just too imperfect. Now I have the element expanded when you reach the page. When you click the "x", it retracts and shows an "i" icon. When you click the "i", the element expands.